# Clock port and any other port of a register should not be driven by the same signal source

Tags: fpga, vhdl, intel-fpga, quartus-ii

I get this Warning from Altera Design Assistant for the below:

Clock port and any other port of a register should not be driven by the 
same signal source

Critical Warning (308012): Node 
"App_Logic:inst1|LGVCtrl:inst1|i_Skal:inst|s_clk"

I previously made some changes to this to meet Timing requirements. I 
tried driving just a '1' instead of driving the sys_clk to v_clk. But 
the timing requirements do not meet when I do so. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried to understand what your code is trying to do here, but your error shows a misunderstanding of one of the fundamentals of how your code will run:

```
v_clk := sys_clk; -- '1';
```

You have assumed that because your process works from the rising edge of `sys_clk`, that when your code reaches this point, `sys_clk` will have the value of `'1'`. This will be true in simulation, but in the real hardware, there is no way that this value of `'1'` will make the setup time for the register you have described. This is made worse by the path from your FPGA's clock network for `sys_clk` to the register being shorter than to the data pin. Additionally, it is bad practice to use a clock as data, and this in itself is prone to timing problems.

Moving on to the actual functionality, the only assignment to `v_clk` is the line above, so why is this signal not simply `'1'`?

I think if you understand these issues and revise your design, your problem will probably go away.

Comment: Will a `v_clk= '1' `not going to be a 1 on the lpm_divider clock throughout ?(but yes, a rising edge of sys clock will also drive only `1` on the divider clock I suppose). Is there a way/ is it necessary to toggle the divider clock? A negative hold slack arises when a 1 is driven to `v_clk.`

Comment: @AlexKrish have you simulated this design at all? `v_clk` and `s_clk` always being `'1'` after the first `sys_clk` edge probably isn't what you wanted. I would say you should arrive at a design that works in simulation before worrying about whether your timing constraints are met.

Comment: I agree with other comments. Please take your time to build your knowledge from solid ground. Start with simple combinatorial logic, then a FF, then a register, a counter, etc. Your code writing style shows you have not grasped the essence of VHDL, which is, to DESCRIBE Hardware. VHDL is NOT a software programming language.